# finding datatable that isnt under table's list in oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Im not sure how to explain this, but..
the program im working on in somehow recognizing a table named 'Transactions' and the table isnt found under the table's list in the database.
Im kinda lost on how to find it ..
then I saw that line:

```
private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Transactions));
```

and I was thinking maybe it reads the transactions from a log? if so, where do I find that log and how do both my program and oracle developer can pull data from that table.

Comment: A synonym is points to another object, (usually) owned by someone else who granted you privileges to use it. For example, if user named SCOTT granted you SELECT privilege on its EMP table, you could then reference it as `select * from scott.emp`, or you could create a synonym: `create synonym scotts_emp for scott.emp` and then reference it without specifying owner name, i.e. `select * from scotts_emp`

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Please do take the [tour] and read up on [ask] and [answer] for more information on how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: ty! was also wondering if theres a way in which I can declare the name "transactions" in some kind of a query and it'd show me that its a synonym of table "transactions_encrypted" for example ( assuming I couldnt find out that the table was a synonym )